# JQuery UI Tabs Collapse all except one tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple JQuery UI tabs menu working, and I set it up so that all the links except the first (Home) will expand/collapse, and clicking the "Home" item will just redirect to the same page.

```
    $("#tabs").tabs({
    collapsible: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.index == 0){//home
            window.location.href = 'test.html';
        }
    }
});
```

Though this works, when The "Home" tab is active, and you click on any other tab for the first time, both tabs get the active class applied for some reason. This only happens the first time. Selecting the same tab or other tabs again does not cause that problem. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

[You can see the demo here](http://www.ephantom.net/test.html)

Comment: dunno if it notifies you when I edit my answer but I added a new jsfiddle with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 problems:

1. your href of "#" is causing errors
2. not having a reference for home seems to also cause errors.

http://jsfiddle.net/D7kqG/3/ seems to have the functionality you want-- you'd just have to style the "home" div to have no height/width to look the way you want.

EDIT: would have expected this to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/D7kqG/4/

(i.e. collapse the home tab whenever it's clicked) But it isn't adding the class...

Alright, this should be exactly what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/D7kqG/5/

It's collapsing and expanding the content div automatically for the home tab.

Comment: I originally had the home href going to a "home" div. The problem with that approach is that the home tab also becomes collapsible and looks horrible since there is no content for it. I just want the home tab to not collapse at all (but have every other tab collapsible), but have the active class applied to it every time it is clicked. My first approach did this, except for the multiple active tab anomaly.

Comment: whoops pasted the wrong fiddle... just a sec. You can style the home div so that when it "collapses" it won't really do anything.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say the home tab should not expand or collapse at all. Basically it should just be a static menu item while every other tab expands/collapses.

Comment: Yeah, I understand you, but you should be able to make it look like a static menu item without actually being a static menu item so that you don't get these errors.

Comment: Changed the jsfiddle link... working on getting the look you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the first() on your selector.
Here is the reference: http://api.jquery.com/first/

Hope this helps.